# Cómo mostrar un array de JSON sino conozco su estructura

Tags: javascript, html, json

Necesito mostrar una lista de JSON en html con javascript pero no conozco su estructura

Comment: Hola, bienvenida a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Una cosa importante es que indiques lo que tú has intentado. Entiendo que tu pregunta es bastante clara, pero se pide que muestres un mínimo de esfuerzo de tu parte. Por otra parte, hablas de *lista* que es interpretable como *Array*, las respuestas recibidas atacan directamente a un Objeto. Estaría bien que aclararas un poco lo que recibes como *lista*. Saludos

Comment: Por favor, usa el boton [edit]. Agrega a tu pregunta la informacion suficiente como para que podamos armar una respuesta. Muestra tu html, explica que estructura es la que no conoces y como te gustaria mostrarlo, y que intentaste.

Comment: Mostrar el html es casi irrelevante, que puede cambiar en relación a la pregunta? un par de innerText's. me parece que desplegar la estructura de un objeto del que no se conoce la estructura no necesita de mayor información.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Así puedes capturar la respuesta que te llega con el json y printarla directamente a un HTML pero no sera nada bonito.

```
const jsonString= JSON.stringify(respuestaJsonServidor);
```

Comment: Cómo puedo hacer para que se vea "bonito"?

Answer (score -1):

Hay muchas maneras, estos son algunos ejemplos:

```js
const obj = {prop:1,prop2:2};

Object.entries(obj).forEach(e=>console.log(e));

Object.keys(obj).forEach(e=>console.log(e+" --> "+obj[e]));

for(let prop in obj){
    console.log("propiedad: "+prop);
    console.log("valor: "+obj[prop]);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Si en las propiedades puede haber otros objetos o arrays habría que hacer algo recursivo.